# How to deploy root certificate in embedded Linux system?

Tags: linux, security, openssl, certificates

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24).
And there runs a web application, which connects to server through security protocol.
So it links to `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so`.

When it is started in target board, it complained about `ca path:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt, no such file or directory`.
I don'k know anything about security, :-(, I don't know where should that file come from or how to generate such file in my embedded Linux system?

Thanks,

Comment: This file stores the certification authorities that your system trusts. Do you connect (as a client) to any outer services from your embedded device? If not, probably an empty file would do.

Comment: The system should connect to a private server setup by my company, and I think the connection is being secured by libssl and libcrypto. And the client started up with the error message I posted in the question.

Comment: So you have to put the certificate of the CA that signed those servers there. Usually in a Linux environment you use `openssl` to create that file, but if you didn't setup those private server, you should contact the operators of the servers to provide you with the file.